# Margins/Borders in the figure environment

Tags: floats, beamerposter

I am designing a poster using the beamerposter package. Many of the blocks I have on this poster have, as to be expected, figures. My problem is that, in many cases, the figures are at the end of the block, and they leave a few lines of emptiness before the next block begins. This is especially ugly in comparison with blocks ending with text.
I have read somewhere that the figure environment, as well as other floats, comes with margins. What I haven't found yet is a way to avoid that. Any help in this matter would be appreciated.

Here is a MWE, adapted from the examples at http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{I6dv}
}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a2,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}  % e.g. custom size poster
  \title[Fancy Posters]{Making Really Fancy Posters with \LaTeX}
  \author[Dreuw \& Deselaers]{Philippe Dreuw and Thomas Deselaers}
  \institute[RWTH Aachen University]{Human Language Technology and Pattern Recognition,RWTH Aachen University}
  \date{Jul. 31th, 2007}

% added packages
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{} 

    \begin{block}{\large Block with Figure}
      \justifying
      \lipsum[1]
      \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{longtable}[c]{m{0.17\linewidth} m{0.23\linewidth} m{0.23\linewidth} m{0.23\linewidth}}
          \multirow{2}{*}[-40]{two rows should be enough right now} &
          \begin{overpic}{figures/example.jpg}
            \put(70,90){fat cat}
          \end{overpic} &
          \begin{overpic}{figures/example.jpg}
            \put(70,90){fat cat}
          \end{overpic} \\
          & \begin{overpic}{figures/example.jpg}
            \put(70,90){fat cat}
          \end{overpic} &
          \begin{overpic}{figures/example.jpg}
            \put(70,90){fat cat}
          \end{overpic}
        \end{longtable}
        \caption{Example figure showing my fat cat.}
      \end{figure}
    \end{block}

    \begin{block}{\large Next Block}
      \lipsum[2]
    \end{block}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Screenshot of the relevant part of the MWE result:
[image: Screenshot of part of a beamerposter where the end of the block contains too mcuh white space.]

Comment: Do you want them to float? I ask because it seems that on a poster you are probably positioning things quite precisely and might not want LaTeX trying to optimise their position.

Comment: Well, actually, since the figures always come at the end of a box, and LaTeX won't move them outside of that, floating is not a problem.

Comment: OK. But if the fact that you are using a `figure` environment is causing the issue you want to eliminate, and you don't need them to float, just don't use such an environment and then you won't get any added marginal space.

Comment: OK, so what else can I use? I'm sorry, I'm still quite new to LaTeX and I only know the figure environment to get numbered figures, and the table/longtable environment to organise them as in the example.